# How to filter if with 2 variables

Tags: magento, filter, attributes

I want to show some data if attribute_set is 1 and attributeText is Zero

AttributeSetId = 10
Attribute = myattribute, contain: Zero, One, Force

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeSetId() == "10"): && ($_product->getAttributeText('myattribute') == "Zero"):?> 

My data

<?php endif; ?>
```

What is wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Resolved by myself :

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeSetId() == "10" && $_product->getAttributeText('myattribute') == "Zero"):?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some misplaced brackets.

```
<?php 
if ($_product->getAttributeSetId() == "10" && 
    $_product->getAttributeText('myattribute') == "Zero")  {
?>
My data
<?php } ?>
```

I prefer to use braces but you can use if/endif if you prefer.

Comment: There's no difference in terms of performance. I prefer it because it's the style I'm used to, and (importantly) you can use "brace matching" in a text editor to switch between the opening and closing braces (e.g. Ctrl+M in Sublime Text). See [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/13nksj/what_is_this_style_called_if_endif/).